# Namespace Aliasing in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, undefined-behavior

It is widely known that adding declarations/definitions to `namespace std` results in undefined behavior. The only exception to this rule is for template specializations.

What about the following "hack"?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace std_
{
  void Foo()
  {
    std::clog << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  }

  using namespace std;
}

int main()
{
  namespace std = std_;

  std::Foo();
}
```

Is this really well-defined as far as the standard is concerned? In this case, I'm really not adding anything to `namespace std`, of course. Every compiler I've tested this on seems to happily swallow this.

---

Before someone makes a comment resembling "why would you ever do that?" -- this is just to satisfy my curiosity...

Comment: Compilers aren't required to diagnose or reject code that results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I realize that, Tyler. The point in testing code on several popular ones is that one of them might. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefining `std` as an alias is okay, as long as you are not in the global declarative region:

> In a declarative region, a namespace-alias-definition can be used to redefine a namespace-alias declared in that declarative region to refer only to the namespace to which it already refers.

Since you define the alias in `main()`, it shadows the global `std` name. That's why this works, should work, and is perfectly fine according to the standard. You're not adding anything to the `std` namespace, and this "hack" only serves to confuse the human reader of the code.

Comment: A function body is a new declarative region.

Comment: Thomas, see Charles' comment. I'm doing this in a new region.

Comment: I can only think of one legitimate use for this right off the bat. Modifying the behavior of some header-only library code without actually touching the library file itself. Probably only useful for testing, though.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `main`, after the namespace alias definition, `std` refers to the alias `std` for the `std_` namespace. The "usual" `std` namespace is hidden, much as a function local variable would hide a global variable with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding anything to `std::`. You're adding to `std_::`, then declaring an alias named `std::`.

I never knew that there is a rule you can't add to `std::`. Is that correct? If so, I'm guessing that the rule only exists to reserve the namespace for future expansion. So you really don't have to hack anything if you really want to augment `std::`.

Someone post if you know of a compiler that does NOT allow such a thing...